# How make mysql query fast using indexing

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have almost 25000 rows in table **questions** and i have the following query also. Is it possible to implement indexing in order to make the query more efficient. If so please give me an example code. I have ajax call on each key enter.

```
SELECT question, url_question FROM `questions` 
WHERE detail LIKE '%a%' OR question LIKE '%a%';
```

Comment: It is not possible to use indexes for this sort of query (with LIKE, only prefix searches can be indexed, but you're searching for something anywhere in the string). If you're searching for whole words, full-text searching may be an option.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Good comment. You should post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a Fulltext Key on your fields, like this

```
ALTER TABLE questions
ADD FULLTEXT KEY `detail` (`IX_detail`);
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE questions
ADD FULLTEXT KEY `question` (`IX_question`);
```

Answer (score 1):

No way if you want to search for single letter.
Starting from 3 you can use fulltext search

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize queries using the MySQL EXPLAIN function - see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html

Connect to your MySQL server and execute the following statement:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN $YOURSTATEMENTGOESHERE;
```

MySQL then will return an useful overview of all lines/columns affacted by this statement. Based on this information you can add some efficient indexes.

Read also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html to get a better understanding how MySQL uses Indexes.

Answer (score 0):

keep check on search length if you can and do not send request if string length less then 2 or 3 that will stop unnecessary request, further you can set limit in sql query. it will imporove performance